# Sorting by string with numerics and spaces

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of units that are named by 'Codes' and displayed like so:

- NP/417A
- NP 416
- NP/418F
- NP/418C
- NP111
- NP112

These units are queried from the database in the following object:

```
var units = _unitService.GetBySiteId(site.SiteId);
```

Which can then be used to order the units by 'code':

```
units = units.OrderBy(u => u.Code);
```

However, I need the units to display numerically and also alphabetically if they are the same unit code, also ignoring any white space or "/" characters messing the ordering up with LINQ.. For example the correct order of the list of units above would be:

- NP111
- NP112
- NP 416
- NP/417A
- NP/418C
- NP/418F

How would sorting the units in this way be achieved using LINQ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @dib do you want it sorted only by the values in each object? if that is the case, simply replace the alphabets by blank and convert to integers.

Comment: How should `NP 213` and `NP 31` be ordered?

Comment: check this out: http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/12/13/natural-sorting. I tested and it seems to solve your problem.

Comment: It would be nice to see that your sample input and sample output data matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be inclined to use a class like this:

```
public class Code
{
    private Match _match = null;
    public Code(string raw)
    {
        _match = Regex.Match(raw, @"^([A-Z]*)([^0-9]*)(\d+)(.*)$");
    }
    public string Prefix { get { return _match.Groups[1].Value; } }
    public string Separator { get { return _match.Groups[2].Value; } }
    public int Number { get { return int.Parse(_match.Groups[3].Value); } }
    public string Suffix { get { return _match.Groups[4].Value; } }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}/{1:00000}{2}", this.Prefix, this.Number, this.Suffix);
    }
}
```

Then just do this:

```
var codes = new []
{
    "NP/417A",
    "NP 416",
    "NP/418F",
    "NP/418C",
    "NP111",
    "NP112",
};

var ordered = codes.OrderBy(c => new Code(c).ToString()).ToArray();
```

Which gives:

```
NP111
NP112
NP 416
NP/417A
NP/418C
NP/418F
```

But you could also use this code like this:

```
var ordered =
    from c in codes
    let code = new Code(c)
    orderby code.Prefix, code.Number, code.Suffix
    select c;
```

I would normally go on to implement `GetHashCode` and `Equals` on this class to be able to use it as a key in dictionaries or for grouping purposes.

---

To handle other cases I would look at doing something simple to start with like this:

```
public class Code
{
    public Code(string raw)
    {
        if (raw == "SUITE FIVE")
        {
            this.Prefix = raw;
            this.Separator = "/";
            this.Number = 0;
            this.Suffix = "";
        }
        else
        {
            var match = Regex.Match(raw, @"^([A-Z]*)([^0-9]*)(\d+)(.*)$");
            this.Prefix = match.Groups[1].Value;
            this.Separator = match.Groups[2].Value;
            this.Number = int.Parse(match.Groups[3].Value);
            this.Suffix = match.Groups[4].Value;
        }
    }
    public string Prefix { get; private set; }
    public string Separator { get; private set; }
    public int Number { get; private set; }
    public string Suffix { get; private set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}/{1:00000}{2}", this.Prefix, this.Number, this.Suffix);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you would use a class while you can use an `IComparer<T>`? (Sure, it's a class, but it's the standard approach)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer - I agree `IComparer<T>` is the standard approach to providing custom sorting. However, the custom class like this provides a "view model" like approach to break down the code and apply custom logic against it. The line `orderby code.Prefix, code.Number, code.Suffix` is a good example of this - it is far more explicit as to what is going on when sorting.

Comment: More explicit than "OrderByDateComparer" class name... I'm not sure if I want to see the internals of what fields are used to order rather than "I just want a sorted set ordered by some criteria (name)"... BTW, it's just my opinion!!!

Comment: Thanks guys, found this solution to be a bit more suited and cleaner to implement so marked this as correct answer. Also, on one of the tables data it also contains a unit code like "SUITE FIVE" which causes the RegEx to fail looking for an int on the Match. Is altering the reg ex /class the best way to allow for this format along with the others?

Comment: You certainly could change the regex, but if you have too many odd codes then you might need to deconstruct in constructor and just assign properties. That might be simpler. I'll have a look if I can add that class.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is using a *sorted set*. You can either store your values directly to a sorted set or build one just for the sake of having the values ordered by some criteria as return value of your method.

For example:

```
public class Site
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class AscendingSiteComparer : IComparer<Site>
{
    // Maybe it's not the best regular expression ever, but if your site
    // ids start with letters either in capital or lower case, it will
    // work!
    private readonly static Regex replaceRegex = new Regex(@"[a-z]+\s*([0-9]+)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    public int Compare(Site x, Site y)
    {
        int a = int.Parse(replaceRegex.Replace(x.Id, "$1"));
        int b = int.Parse(replaceRegex.Replace(y.Id, "$1"));

        if (a > b)
            return 1;
        else if (a < b)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Later in your code:

```
var sites = new[] { new Site { Id = "NP 417" }, new Site { Id = "NP 318" }, new Site { Id = "NP 418" }, new Site { Id = "NP111" }, new Site { Id = "NP112" } };

SortedSet<Site> orderedSites = new SortedSet<Site>(sites, new AscendingSiteComparer());
```

Now your sites will be ordered in *ascending order* by default.

As I said above, you can also build the sorted set directly without providing an `IEnumerable<T>` during its construction:

```
// While you add items in a disordered way, they're stored in the
// desired order!
SortedSet<Site> orderedSites = new SortedSet<Site>(new AscendingSiteComparer());
orderedSites.Add(new Site { Id = "NP 417" });
orderedSites.Add(new Site { Id = "NP 318" });
orderedSites.Add(new Site { Id = "NP111" });
```

At the end of the day, if need to provide your site collection using a fixed order, I wouldn't return `List<T>` but `SortedSet<T>` because other methods may add new items and they'll be **stored in order**, and you don't need to `.OrderBy(...)` whenever you want to re-order the collection (until there's a case where you need a different order, of course...!).

### The LINQ way...

If you feel that the sorted set may be an overkill, you can use LINQ too with `OrderBy` extension method:

```
public class StringAscendingComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    private readonly static Regex replaceRegex = new Regex(@"[a-z]+\s*([0-9]+)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {

        int a = int.Parse(replaceRegex.Replace(x, "$1"));
        int b = int.Parse(replaceRegex.Replace(y, "$1"));

        if (a > b)
            return 1;
        else if (a < b)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}

var orderedSites2 = sites.OrderBy(site => site.Id, new StringAscendingComparer());
```

Answer (score 0):

Pick any of the following depending on what you need:

```
/* Remove spaces and sort */
.OrderBy(u=>u.Replace(" ",""))

/* Sort based on last 3 characters */
.OrderBy(u=>u.Substring(u.Length-3))

 /* Sort based on last 3 characters as integer */
.OrderBy(u=>int.Parse(u.Substring(u.Length-3)))

/* Remove all non-digits and sort as string */
.OrderBy(u=>Regex.Replace(u,"[^0-9]",""));

/* Remove all non-digits and sort as integer */
.OrderBy(u=>int.Parse(Regex.Replace(u,"[^0-9]","")));

/* Pull out all the digits and sort as integer */
.OrderBy(u=>int.Parse(Regex.Match(u,"([0-9]+)").Groups[1].Value));
```